# Word for describing someone who always gives their best on every job

Tags: word-request

I’m looking for a word to describe a professional that is not necessarily talented, but is always giving his best effort on every assignment.
The best I could come up with is diligent.

Comment: Have you had any thoughts so we do not duplicate your researches? Any particular field of activity, work, school, home, ...?

Comment: Can you give more information about how they give their best?  I'm drawing a blank on common words that mean this in a general sense, so I suspect people would use more specific words or phrases.  Best I've come up with is "stalwart" or "dependable", but neither means what you're asking for, stalwart is quite uncommon and both of them, though mostly positive, are not 100% positive affect I'd say.

Comment: A word with mostly negative affect is "perfectionist" -- and of course many would say a perfectionist does not give their best at all

Comment: I edited the description to try being more specific. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is described as [***conscientious***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/conscientiousness), that doesn't necessarily imply they ***are*** good at their job - just that they ***want*** to be good (though obviously ["the wish is father to the deed"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the%20wish%20is%20father%20to%20the%20deed%22) in many cases).

> **conscientiousness**
> *The quality of **wishing** to do one's work or duty well and thoroughly.*

Comment: Tha's exactly the word I was looking for. Thank you! Such a pity that it's a long/complicated word. I planned on using it for marketing.

Comment: ***diligent*** is very close in meaning (though it tends to emphasise ***making effort*** more than ***taking care***), but both that and ***assiduous*** are at least as "complicated" (assuming what you mean there is *erudite, unfamiliar to the less-well-educated* :)

Comment: I think diligent is good too.  In fact when I hear diligent, I immediately think of the phrase "due diligence", because most of the times I hear that word it's in that context.  Due diligence is a legal phrase (comes up in the context of putting a formerly private company on the public stock exchange) - so there are serious consequences if you fail at it.  Because of that, "diligent" sounds to me like it likely means successful effort.

Comment: By the way, happy you posted here Edson, but if it's useful to you and you're not in the habit, I bet if you look up "diligent" in a thesaurus you're likely to find both the words @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica suggested